# Delphi: Set Browsers Homepage

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I want my application to be able to set IE, Firefox, Chrome & Operas homepages when a button is pressed. I understand IEs homepage is set in the registry, which I understand how to change, but can anyone give me any help with the others? Thanks

Comment: It's a parents application that only allows a selection of kids websites. The homepage changes to a homepage for kids. Nothing to do with malware

Answer (score 3):

**Chrome** stores the homepage in a file called 'Preferences'. On Windows XP, this is located at;

> C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

On Vista+, it's located at;

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

This file is JSON format, and so it can be opened and viewed as plain text. In order to change the homepage, you'd need to load the JSON from this file, and change the `homepage` field value. You may also need to change the `homepage_changed` field value in order for it to stick. Using something like [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) to change the field would be an easy solution (if I get time, I'll write up some example code later).

**Firefox** uses a `pref.js` file to store it's settings, and realistically, a way of changing this would be to load this file, find the something that's along the lines of;

```
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "[URL]");
```

...and edit it as appropriate before saving the file. This should be a simple task using some simple find-and-replace code. I'd **strongly** advise that you use a `pos()` function though, as it could be that the end-user has already got their own custom homepage set and so searching for a preset string (e.g. `[URL]`) may not work, and certainly wouldn't be reliable.

A quick search hasn't given me enough information about **Opera** to provide a solution, but I'll keep looking and respond if I do find such a way.

---

Note that none of these methods have been tested and are merely provided based upon some very quick research.

Comment: Isn't Opera very similar to Firefox?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've not used Opera for many years (last time was when it was made available for free), and even when I did it was only for a short time.

Comment: Yeah I only open it when I need to test some cross-compatibility web page due to a bug report, otherwise I don't bother with it